# Basic LINQ to SQL Question: How to call stored procedure and retrieve single return value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm new to LINQ and am having a problem getting proper results from a simple (working) stored procedure that takes no parameters and returns a single Integer.  When calling this sproc with LINQ its returnvalue is always 0.  When run using tableadapter or directly on the sql server it works, returning 6 digit values like 120123.

Here is my LINQ code:

```
Dim MeetingManager As New MeetingManagerDataContext
Dim MeetingID As Integer = MeetingManager.NewMeetingID().ReturnValue
```

Here is the NewMeetingID procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewMeetingID]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SELECT UniqueNumber
    FROM tblTakeANumber
    WHERE NumberID = 1

        BEGIN
            UPDATE tblTakeANumber SET UniqueNumber = UniqueNumber + 1
            WHERE (NumberID = 1)
        END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN
END
```

Am I missing someting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return value is the value that a stored procedure returns, like:

```
create procedure TestProc()
as 
return 1
```

But your stored procedure is probably selecting a result, like:

```
create procedure TestProc()
as 
select 1 as Col1
```

To retrieve the first column, specify it by name:

```
Dim Col1 As Integer = TestDataCintext.TestProc().Single().Col1
```

EDIT: Per your comment, here's how you could modify the stored procedure to return the integer.  Note the `(updlock)` and isolation level:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewMeetingID]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    declare @UniqueNumber int

    SELECT  @UniqueNumber = UniqueNumber
    FROM    tblTakeANumber (updlock)
    WHERE   NumberID = 1

    UPDATE  tblTakeANumber 
    SET     UniqueNumber = @UniqueNumber + 1
    WHERE   NumberID = 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN @UniqueNumber
END
```

Comment: Your exactly right Andomar, its selecting from a table. When running it on the SQL server the Return Value is always 0, but it returns a one column (UniqueNumber), one row result table. Can I modify the sproc to return the number as its Return Value? (we dont have a DBA). I've added the existing sproc code to my question.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Adomar all the help!!